# Kotlin interface in not accessible from Java class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have created an interface on kotlin.

```
interface IDataManager{
    val dataType: String?
}
```

Now I am trying to get its variable in my java class, like following.

```
public static DataWrapper getInstance(IDataManager iDataManager) {
    dataType= iDataManager.dataType;
    return instance;
}
```

But I am getting `error: cannot find symbol iDataManager.dataType`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please call getter function to get a value of the variable:

```
dataType = iDataManager.getDataType();
```

If we use properties on Kotlin side we should use **getters** and **setters** to access those properties on Java side.

Comment: Thank you so much !! :)

Answer (score 0):

**edit - as Alexey points out in the comments, this doesn't work for interfaces, since the property needs a backing field and properties in interfaces can't have those.** *It's still useful to know, but it doesn't apply to the OP's question*

As well as what Sergey said, you can add the `@JvmField` annotation on things if you want to expose them as a field instead of generating the getters and setters

```
interface IDataManager{
    @JvmField val dataType: String?
}
```

`@JvmStatic` is another useful one for Java interop, you can put it on properties and functions in companion objects, so instead of this

```
Utils.Companion.coolUtility()
```

you can do this (like you're used to)

```
Utils.coolUtility()
```

Comment: `@JvmField` won't work on an interface property, because interfaces can't have instance fields.

Comment: Aww heck, you're right, sorry! It's good to be aware of them at least (for the situations where you actually can use them)